# Finding all possible groups of two numbers in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm

If I have an input array, and I have to find all possible group of 2 numbers that satisfy the condition that `a%b = k` and `a` is towards left of `b` in the array. Here, `k` is the input and the array is the input as well. I am doing it in `O(n^2)`. Simply by taking two loops and finding such numbers, can I do better?

```
For eg:
 7 3 1 and `k = 1`
```

Then, (7,3) form one such group and I have to find such groups.

Comment: Can you even print all pairs in a list in less than O(n^2)? I don't think that is possible?

Comment: One simple optimization is that you can ignore all values for a less than k and for b less than k+1. I don't understand your example though, 7%3=1

Comment: @Sumurai8, well that's the question about. Can we do it in less than O(n^2)?

Comment: @samgak, well that ain't much of an optimization.

Comment: No, you can't, because the size of your output is O(n^2).